# what is the difference between trivial and non trivial objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I am actually not sure to understand the difference between a trivial and non-trivial object. For instance, it is said [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trivial-classes-c/) that a trivial object:

- occupies a contiguous memory area
- does not contains user-provided constructor/operator/destructor.

but are objects automatically aligning data in memory ? what if it meets both points but there is methods ? is there something related to POD ?

"trivial" sounds to me like something that can be used kind of the same way as a simple type. But i guess it is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official definition of a trivial type can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType).

In simpler terms, a trivial type is either a fundamental type (`int`, `float`, etc.) or a type composed of only other trivial types, and without any of the special member functions listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable). Other member functions don't play a role.

The point of triviality is that the type can be treated exactly like a fundamental type, in that objects of the type can be copied and moved with `memcpy` and constructed destructed without doing anything. Hence, triviality requires a type be essentially made only of fundamental types. This is what makes the copy, move, construction, and destruction operations relevant to the definition of trivial types. Other member functions don't play a role in triviality just as you can write `void fn( int*, OtherArgs... )` without affecting whether or not an `int` is trivial, because you can think of member functions of `T` as essentially being free functions with the signature `ReturnType member_function( T*, OtherArgs... )` that the compiler let's you call with the syntax `a.member_function( other_args... )`.

As for alignment, it simply isn't all that relevant because it's all taken care of for you. The compiler knows the alignment of the types it's working with, thanks to the strong static type system.

As you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType), all POD types are trivial.

Comment: Note: The "official" definition link is not official.